# Google News in R

Tags: html, r, google-news

I am trying to get info from Google News. This is my code:

```
library(rvest)
library(tidyverse)


news <- function(term) {

  html_dat <- read_html(paste0("https://news.google.com/search?q=",term,"&hl=es-419&gl=US&ceid=US%3Aes-419")) 

  dat <- data.frame(Link = html_dat %>%
                      html_nodes('.VDXfz') %>% 
                      html_attr('href')) %>% 
    mutate(Link = gsub("./articles/","https://news.google.com/articles/",Link))

  news_dat <- data.frame(
    Title = html_dat %>%
      html_nodes('.DY5T1d') %>% 
      html_text(),
    Link = dat$Link,
    Description =  html_dat %>%
      html_nodes('.Rai5ob') %>% 
      html_text()
  )

  return(news_dat)
}

noticias<-news("coronavirus")
```

With this code, I retrieve title, link and description. OK. But I need to get 2 fields more: date and media. For example, If a news about a vaccine for the coronavirus has been published yesterday, date will be that. If the media is New York Times, this field will be that. But I don't find these nodes in the HTML. Some idea to fix my code adding these two fields?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps try this

```
news <- function(term) {
  url <- paste0("https://news.google.com/search?q=", term, "&hl=es-419&gl=US&ceid=US:es-419")
  nodeset <- read_html(url) %>% html_nodes("article")
  tibble::tibble(
    Title = nodeset %>% html_nodes("h3") %>% html_text(), 
    Link = nodeset %>% html_nodes("h3 > a") %>% html_attr("href") %>% xml2::url_absolute(url), 
    Description = nodeset %>% html_nodes("div.Da10Tb.Rai5ob > span") %>% html_text(), 
    Source = nodeset %>% html_nodes("div.QmrVtf.RD0gLb.kybdz > div > a") %>% html_text(), 
    Time = nodeset %>% html_nodes("div.QmrVtf.RD0gLb.kybdz > div > time") %>% html_attr("datetime")
  )
}
```

Output

```
> news("coronavirus")
```

```
# A tibble: 100 x 5
   Title                                Link                                           Description                                        Source   Time     
   <chr>                                <chr>                                          <chr>                                              <chr>    <chr>    
 1 India reporta 41.100 casos nuevos d~ https://news.google.com/articles/CBMikwFodHRw~ "NUEVA DELHI (AP) — India reportó el domingo 41.1~ La Voz ~ 2020-11-~
 2 El ecuatoriano Diego Palacios, de L~ https://news.google.com/articles/CBMigwFodHRw~ "El defensa del LAFC, Diego Palacios, se encuentr~ ESPN De~ 2020-11-~
 3 Coronavirus: Austria endurece medid~ https://news.google.com/articles/CAIiEL2L0sxq~ "El canciller Sebastian Kurz pidió a la población~ DW (Esp~ 2020-11-~
 4 ++Coronavirus hoy: Gobierno alemán ~ https://news.google.com/articles/CAIiEKCZppoU~ "\"Todos los países que levantaron sus restriccio~ DW (Esp~ 2020-11-~
 5 ++Coronavirus hoy++ México supera e~ https://news.google.com/articles/CAIiEK8ndryG~ "El COVID-19 se consolidó como la cuarta causa de~ DW (Esp~ 2020-11-~
 6 Coronavirus en Estados Unidos: 5 ci~ https://news.google.com/articles/CAIiEFFHgJgZ~ "La incertidumbre política y la emergencia sanita~ BBC New~ 2020-11-~
 7 México supera el millón de casos de~ https://news.google.com/articles/CBMiRWh0dHBz~ "México sobrepasó el millón de casos confirmados ~ Reuters~ 2020-11-~
 8 Massachusetts reporta 2.800 casos d~ https://news.google.com/articles/CBMiXmh0dHA6~ "Los casos registrados en la más reciente jornada~ El Tiem~ 2020-11-~
 9 ¿Qué hará NYC para resistir una seg~ https://news.google.com/articles/CBMifWh0dHBz~ "Reaccionan políticos locales a la orden de cerra~ NY1 Not~ 2020-11-~
10 + Coronavirus hoy: Italia suma 544 ~ https://news.google.com/articles/CAIiEJ4KB7k2~ "Argentina registró este sábado (14.11.2020) 8.46~ DW (Esp~ 2020-11-~
# ... with 90 more rows
```

---

**Update**

I never thought of cases as follows:

1. Nested articles.

[image: nested]

2. Missing the date-time attribute.

[image: no-date]

I have updated the code to account for all those cases, but the code becomes much less efficient. Anyway, try this:

```
news <- function(term) {
  url <- paste0("https://news.google.com/search?q=", term, "&hl=es-419&gl=US&ceid=US:es-419")
  nodeset <- read_html(url) %>% html_nodes("article")
  dplyr::bind_rows(lapply(nodeset, function(x) tibble::tibble(
    Title = x %>% html_node(".ipQwMb.ekueJc.RD0gLb") %>% html_text(), 
    Link = x %>% html_node(".ipQwMb.ekueJc.RD0gLb > a") %>% html_attr("href") %>% xml2::url_absolute(url), 
    Description = x %>% html_node("div.Da10Tb.Rai5ob > span") %>% html_text(), 
    Source = x %>% html_node("div.QmrVtf.RD0gLb.kybdz > div > a") %>% html_text(), 
    Time = x %>% html_node("div.QmrVtf.RD0gLb.kybdz > div > time") %>% html_attr("datetime")
  )))
}
```

Comment: Thanks ekoam. But if I try news("EEUU") I get this: Error: Tibble columns must have consistent lengths, only values of length one are recycled:
* Length 100: Columns `Title`, `Link`
* Length 103: Columns `Description`, `Source`, `Time`

Comment: Thanks ekoam, but if I try this: news("VASS"), I get the same error. And with other examples too.